# lightning-radio-group error when setting variant

Tags: lightning-web-components

Trying the following markup in a template:

```
<lightning-radio-group 
    label="Radio Group" 
    options={options} 
    value={value} 
    type="button" 
    variant="label-hidden"></lightning-radio-group>
```

Will result in the following error:

> Error: Unknown public property "variant" of element . This is likely a typo on the corresponding attribute "variant".

This is strange since the [radio-group specifications](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-radio-group/specification) state that this is supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variant attribute was added in summer19

When you are on playground or org < summer 19 (which should in theory not exist anymore):
playground is running an older version than platform, orgs < summer19 too

When you get the error on summer19 orgs:
You should contact SFDC Support - it should work

Comment: It's a shave that the playground is behind the current release.